# Is there an equivalent to Linux's lsusb in Windows?

Tags: windows

To list the plugged in usb devices from software, preferably a shell.

Linux, or at least some Linuies seem to have a command to do that `lsusb`

Answer (score 6):

You can play around with `Get-PnpDevice`, and its Parameters `-Class`, `-Status` and `-InstanceId`

See the different outputs (I used `-Status OK` in all examples, since I believe you need that to get the currently active ones. If you want to see everything, don't use this parameter):

InstanceId (Will only show stuff where InstanceId like 'USB*'):

```
PS C:\> Get-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'USB*' -Status OK

Status     Class           FriendlyName                  InstanceId
------     -----           ------------                  ----------
OK         HIDClass        USB-Input device              USB\VID_03F0&P…
OK         HIDClass        USB-Input device              USB\VID_0B0E&P…
OK         MEDIA           Logitech BRIO                 USB\VID_046D&P…
OK         USB             USB-Root-Hub (USB 3.0)        USB\ROOT_HUB30…
OK         USB             Logitech BRIO                 USB\VID_046D&P…
OK         USB             USB-Composite unit            USB\VID_0B0E&P…
OK         MEDIA           Jabra PRO 9460                USB\VID_0B0E&P…
OK         Image           Logitech BRIO                 USB\VID_046D&P…
OK         HIDClass        USB-Input device              USB\VID_1BCF&P…
OK         HIDClass        USB-Input device              USB\VID_03F0&P…
OK         USB             USB-Composite unit            USB\VID_03F0&P…
```

Class (See the difference to InstanceId, we have one return with InstanceId PCI*):

```
PS C:\> Get-PnpDevice -Class 'USB' -Status OK

Status     Class           FriendlyName                  InstanceId
------     -----           ------------                  ----------
OK         USB             USB-Root-Hub (USB 3.0)        USB\ROOT_HUB30…
OK         USB             Logitech BRIO                 USB\VID_046D&P…
OK         USB             USB-Composite unit            USB\VID_0B0E&P…
OK         USB             Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensi...   PCI\VEN_8086&D…
OK         USB             USB-Composite unit            USB\VID_03F0&P…
```

InstanceId and Class (the most strict one):

```
PS C:\> Get-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'USB*' -Class USB -Status OK

Status     Class           FriendlyName                  InstanceId
------     -----           ------------                  ----------
OK         USB             USB-Root-Hub (USB 3.0)        USB\ROOT_HUB30…
OK         USB             Logitech BRIO                 USB\VID_046D&P…
OK         USB             USB-Composite unit            USB\VID_0B0E&P…
OK         USB             USB-Composite unit            USB\VID_03F0&P…
```

Then you can create a function and put it in your [PowerShell Profile](https://www.howtogeek.com/126469/how-to-create-a-powershell-profile/), and simply use it like you would in Linux

```
PS C:\> Function lsusb { Get-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'USB*' -Class 'USB' -Status OK }
PS C:\> lsusb

Status     Class           FriendlyName                  InstanceId
------     -----           ------------                  ----------
OK         USB             USB-Root-Hub (USB 3.0)        USB\ROOT_HUB30…
OK         USB             Logitech BRIO                 USB\VID_046D&P…
OK         USB             USB-Composite unit            USB\VID_0B0E&P…
OK         USB             USB-Composite unit            USB\VID_03F0&P…
```

Play around with the `Get-PnPDevice` cmdlet and see what fits your needs.

Comment: you can use `Get-PnpDevice -Class 'USB' -Status OK | select FriendlyName,InstanceId` to get a more usable output, or you can select more columns to get uncut contents

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in XP - https://usbdeview.en.softonic.com/.  I remember using it before in my Windoze days, so after a quick scan using Kaperky, I touched wood and ran it.  My only criticism is "too much information".  It seems to list every single thing I've plugged into my system ever!

I'm afraid I don't know anything that will run from a DOS prompt.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Well the output from the lsusb command was verbose to say the least as well, but only displayed was was currently attached.  However, I believe it also listed every single port on every single usb bus.